# Finding our global admin

Tags: administration

We have a sharepoint site with some sub teamsites.

I only have admin rights for one of the sub sites.

Is it somehow possible for me to see the name or mail of our company/global admin?

Comment: I'm not a SPO-user but might the global admin be included in the owner permission group in the subsite maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, out of the box, this is not possible. When you try to access a site, you will get a form where you can type in why you want to get access to this site an the responsible person gets an email an can approve or reject. But there is no other way to find out or look for who is responsible for the Root-Site or the Farm.